# Unknown column 'EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql

[I want to get this table as output but i'm getting this error **Unknown column 'EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID' in 'on clause'**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26TdY.png)

The query which i use is :

```
SELECT * FROM EmployeeDemographics FULL JOIN EmployeeSalary ON EmployeeDemographics.EmployeeID=EmployeeSalary.EmployeeID;
```

Comment: Can u give us the 2 origins tables, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Full Join is not supported in MySQL completely.
So you would have to rely on some workaround joins to accomplish your logic.

```
create table EmployeeDemographics(employeeid integer, firstname varchar(100), lastname varchar(100));
insert into EmployeeDemographics(employeeid, firstname,lastname) values(1, "User1", "TestLastname1");
insert into EmployeeDemographics(employeeid, firstname,lastname) values(2, "User2", "TestLastname2");
insert into EmployeeDemographics(employeeid, firstname,lastname) values(null, "User3", "TestLastname2");


create table EmployeeSalary(id integer, employeeid integer, jobtitle varchar(100), salary integer);
insert into EmployeeSalary(id, employeeid, jobtitle, salary) values(1, 1, "UserJob1", 12345);
insert into EmployeeSalary(id, employeeid, jobtitle, salary) values(2, 2, "UserJob2", 67890);
insert into EmployeeSalary(id, employeeid, jobtitle, salary) values(3, 3, "UserJob3", null);

SELECT ed.firstname, ed.lastname, es.salary
  FROM EmployeeDemographics ed 
    LEFT JOIN EmployeeSalary es 
      ON ed.employeeid = es.employeeid
UNION ALL
  SELECT ed.firstname, ed.lastname, es.salary 
 FROM EmployeeDemographics ed 
    RIGHT JOIN EmployeeSalary es 
      ON ed.employeeid = es.employeeid
WHERE ed.employeeid IS NULL
```

Its a feature [requested](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=18003) long time back, but not yet available.

Comment: why are you using **WHERE ed.employeeid IS NULL** i didnt get that part? btw Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Hey @Ali_Khan_99. Because by the definition of Full join, you would also need data which is null in Table 2 but maps to table 1 through key. i.e. query will be : 
      SELECT * FROM t1
      LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
      UNION ALL
      SELECT * FROM t1
      RIGHT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
     WHERE t1.id IS NULL
------
Also please feel free to mark the comment as answer if this solves your issue. And make sure to use FullJoin here only if you need the very "purpose" of full join fulfilled.